# fputs vs. fprintf and double

Tags: c, file, printf, fputs

I need to put out a double value into an file.
So for all my other string i have to put out i use fputs because i think and timed it that fputs is faster then fprintf.

But if i want to put out the double value i can't do this with fputs so i tried fprintf. This is very slow. I need more time if i replace the fprintf and puts there an fputs("TEST",file);

How can i put out the double as fast as the string. Need i to convert it first to string?

I found some conversion. But if i use them i am as slow as if i use the fprintf.

So how can i put out the double to a file so fast as if i put out a string to the file?

```
  fputs("TEST",fileout); //FAST
  fprintf(fileout, "%f",p); //SLOW
```

EDIT:

Times with fprintf double:

```
END.PROCESSING.DATA: 2013-04-26 08:10:33.000
END.CALC.IN.FILE: 2013-04-26 08:11:13.000
```

Times with fputs strings:

```
END.PROCESSING.DATA: 2013-04-26 08:14:10.000
END.CALC.IN.FILE: 2013-04-26 08:14:37.000
```

The code for that times:

```
now = time (0);
strftime (buff, 100, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000", localtime (&now));
printf ("END.PROCESSING.DATA: %s\n", buff);

//output file
FILE *fileout;
fileout = fopen("out.txt","w");
double p;
for(i=0; i<17000;i++){
  for(j=0; j<i;j++){
    for(z=0;z<400;z++){
      //DO SOME WORK
    }
    p = 1.0;
    fputs(allsubsts[i],fileout);
    fputs(";",fileout);
    fputs(allsubsts[j],fileout);
    fputs(";",fileout);
    //fprintf(fileout, "%.21g", p);
    fputs("TEST",fileout);
    fputs(";\n",fileout);
  }
}
fclose(fileout);

now = time(0);
strftime(buff,100,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.000", localtime(&now));
printf("END.CALC.IN.FILE: %s\n",buff);
```

Changes between the time are only the change that i put the double instead the TEST string in the file.

Comment: Does the file need to be human readable?

Comment: 1. Is it text or binary file? 2. `%f` is for `float`, `%lf` is for `double`.

Comment: @Crozin: No, both `%f` and `%lf` are for double. There is no way to pass a `float` to `fprintf`.

Comment: How are you measuring speed?

Comment: @R..: [Of cource, you're right](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fprintf/) - my mistake.

Comment: Measuring speed with date prints before and after writing to the file...very simple

Comment: have edited my question with a example and how i measuring speed

Comment: `time` (aka "wall clock time") is not reliable for benchmarking. The wall clock time it takes a program to run can be affected by everything else running on your computer. For example, lots of other things are writing to the disk along with your program. You want to know just the resources used by your program. Use the Unix command line tool [`time`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_(Unix)) and only pay attention to user (CPU time used by the program) and system (time spent using system resources such as writing to the disk) times.

Comment: It’s a little silly to ask “How can constructing a string mathematically and then writing it to a file be made as fast as only the latter half of the operation?”, isn’t it?  No one made `fprintf` slow on purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Converting a floating point number to a decimal representation is a fundamentally slow operation. You might try using the `%a` specifier instead of `%f` to store it as a hex float; this should be much faster and would safely preserve the original value rather than a poor approximation. If you need decimal, you should be using `%.21g` or similar, not `%f`, as the latter will lose most of the precision.

If none of this is fast enough for you, then you probably need to save the binary representation of the value directly.

Comment: the binary representation is a very good idea but the file needs to be loaded by an other program so it needs so be in this format...i will try your formats

Answer (score 0):

In C you can use [the ryu library](https://github.com/ulfjack/ryu) to speed up floating-point output by first formatting the number into a buffer and then writing it out. It is not [the fastest method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55326309/471164) but still better than common `printf` implementations.

```c
double n = 0.42;
char buf[32];
d2s_buffered(n, buf);
fputs(buf, file);
```

Using hexadecimal `printf` format (`%a`) is an option too but the result may not be as easy to interpret by humans.

In case you can use C++, the same can be achieved with C++17 [`std::to_char`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) or C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) without extra dependencies. These methods don't depend on locale and normally use faster algorithms for converting binary floating point into the decimal representation.

Comment: The question was tagged C, not C++.

Comment: Ah, missed that.

Comment: Corrected the answer.